# How create account or user for SFTP (Java) ?

Tags: java, linux, sftp, jsch

I see [jsch](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/) but no example for create account or user. 
Thx.

Comment: You don't. SFTP is simply FTP over SSH. You need to create an SSH account on your computer in the standard way.

Comment: @BoristheSpider SFTP is NOT "FTP over SSH", and SSH accounts are not always system accounts.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is sftp = ftp using ssh. So sftp user is ssh user. You may need to use `adduser` command to add an user.